# How to store session data into the database when the user logs out

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have 1 `DropdownList` and 2 `Textbox` in `page1.aspx`.. I enter my search condition and click on go which populates the result.

Now I go to `page2.aspx`..here I have two `Textbox`.. I do the same thing which I did in `page1.aspx`.

Now when I go back to `page1.aspx` the search condition which I entered doesn't exist, it has gone back to it's default value. What I wanted is for the search condition to be retained when I come back to the old page.

It also should be retained when the user (not an anonymous user) Logout and Login.

I have tried using `sessions` but it's not working out.

Thought of using `session+database`, but no clue how to use it.

Comment: Session is not working ? What do you mean by that ?

Comment: On go button `click` save that value in session and on `page1_load` check if session is not null then set session value, you may be mistaking somewhere else using session your problem will be sloved

Comment: @satindersingh: he also want to retain the search criterai once user logout and login back..in that case it will not work

Comment: @RohitVyas: yeah then in that case cookie will work.

Comment: Do you use EntityFramework or Ado.Net ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the search criteria in database in a new table specific to users. you can add/modify the search criteria in table at the time when user hit the "Search" button. If there are no record found in table for the logged in user than load the default values on your page. You can save the search criteria in a xml or in any string whichever is comfortable.

Comment: could you please explain it with a sample code..I'm a beginner in C#..haven't worked much in coding...just wanted to know how to store values in the session to a database

Answer (score 0):

I think in these situations you can save setting in `cookies`:

When user select an item of `dropdownlist` save it

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie("NameOfCookie");
        hc.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60);//this cookie will be remove after 60 seconds.
        hc.Value = ddl.SelectedValue;// save here for later using
        Response.Cookies.Add(hc);//sending to user
    }
```

And in `page loading` event get value from cookie:

```
if (Request.Cookies.Get("NameOfCookie") != null)
{
      string value= Request.Cookies.Get("NameOfCookie").Value;
      ddl.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
}
```